# Are the stackexchange sites one big database?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, personal-statistics

The reason for this question is to find the answer to another question.  At this moment in time:

On StackOverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/users/573261/richard-aka-cyberkiwi

[image: On StackOverflow]

On StackExchange : https://stackexchange.com/users/eb9ed114e20e4d79ad7869fa92413e04

[image: On StackExchange]

I had always though that the SE family was just one big database.

It would be nice to get an answer to why the counts don't match as well.

Comment: Caching? That's my guess.

Comment: @jjnguy I know data.se uses some nifty caching, you think `stackexchange.com` uses caching too? It is not using http headers if it is, since each retrieval has a different modified date.

Comment: I don't think they use http caching.  It is caching on the backend on top of their data.

Answer (score 4):

I know for sure that each site is in its own database, so the one for StackExchange.com would be in its own as well.

I suspect that all the data that appears on StackExchange.com is generated from periodic jobs that pull data like recent high answer scores, reputation changes, etc., from each of the site databases.

The different types of data probably get updated on different schedules staggered throughout the day, so if you've been upvoted between updates, that explains why the information is out of sync.